# How much math was "Broken" by Russell's Paradox?

Tags: soft-question, math-history, paradoxes, mathematicians

As you know, the phrase "the set of all sets that don't contain themselves" caused a paradox that "broke" (made trivial) Naive set theory. How much mathematics had to be redone because of this? Most mathematics was being formulated in it, so it was obviously bad that it was inconsistent. On the other hand, things like *Pythagoras' Theorem* or *Euclid's Proof of the Infinitude of Primes* or *the irrationality of $\pi$*, would work the same regardless of foundation.

How much mathematical labor had to be redone or was simply lost when the paradox was found?

Comment: A proper class of math.

Comment: At the time of Russell's Paradox, very little mathematics was done with Set Theory as the background theory.

Comment: @CameronBuie I doubt mathematicians did literally *infinite* math at this point, let alone a class of it.

Comment: It seems a lot of the work that Frege had put into _Grundlagen der Arithmetik_ was undone, at least [according to this.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RussellsAntinomy.html) But that was one as-yet-unpublished book, and the idea that math _needed_ a rigorous foundation in something as basic as set theory was still relatively new then.

Comment: @PyRulez: True, only a finite class of practiced math was broken, but said broken theorem schema could be applied to a proper class of putative sets, no? (Also, my original statement was intended mostly as humor, rather than as any kind of rigorous answer to the question--hence the comment.)

Comment: Naive set theory was found be inconsistent in that both the statement $\exists r:\forall x:[x\in r \iff x\notin x]$ and its negation where shown by Russell to be theorems in that system. Although I am fascinated by such matters, IMHO the various work-arounds proposed haven't have much of an impact at all on mainstream mathematics (e.g. number theory, classical analysis), most of the foundational issues in these fields being largely resolved centuries before Russell. Still, it's nice to have a workable set of axioms with which one can resolve minor disputes as they come up, e.g. $0^0$.  ;^)